# The right way to find average change in percentages

Tags: mean

I want find how much percentage changed on average. Am I doing it the right way?

Say I start with value 100 and change the value by some percentage

[image]

Can I say that the avg. change is 2.46 % (adding all percentages and dividing by 11)?

[image]

If so, why doesn't the value tally (130.57 instead of 125.18) if I start with 100 and change the value by 2.46% 11 times?

enter image description here

Comment: Suppose you start with $100$, increase by $20\%$ to $120$ and then decrease by $20\%$ to $96$.  Can you say the average change was $0\%$ and apply this twice?

Comment: Thanks. what / if would be the right way to find avg % change over a period of time if I want to use averages as the reference value?

Comment: There is not a right way, but one approach is to use logarithms, so in my example you start at $\log_e(100) \approx 4.605$ and then add $\log_e\left(\frac{120}{100}\right)=\log_e(1.2) \approx 0.182$ you get $log_e(120)\approx 4.787$; then add $\log_e\left(\frac{96}{120}\right)=\log_e(0.8) \approx -0.223$ to get $\log_e(96) \approx 4.564$.  Adding the average change $\frac{0.182-0.223}{2}$ twice to the starting point $\log_e(100)$ would get to the same end point $\log_e(96)$.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Manu.  I am confident you can find your question answered by searching our site for [average change percentage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=average+change+percentage).

Comment: Percentages can be very confusing, as you are discovering. It's often best to try to avoid them and evaluate results close to the original scales, except perhaps at a very final summary stage of presentation. See [this post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/), for example.